# grunt.file.read replacing content to ...(length: xxxxx) in files with +10k chars

Tags: gruntjs, iconv

In my gruntfile, i'm using this code line to read a file, and assign his content to a variable:

`var content = grunt.file.read(file);`

The file reading action it's ok, but if the file is large, like +10K chars, it's shows the first +-10k of chars and replace the rest for something like that:

`[*Something around the first 10k char appears here (OK) and then ...*]
...(length: 62967)`

i searched through the entire web, but i'm not sure if is the grunt that is doing this, or the iconv-lite used by grunt to decode the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error above occurs just when inspecting via web developer tools. Maybe the browser has a limitation to show the entire content (when it's bigger) of a variable.

using the `console.log()`, i can see the entire content.